# Use variable for the view without modifying the model

Tags: angularjs

I have an object with a list of items X inside, each X has list of Y and each Y has a list of Z.

I would like to hide the span when clicking the button. I can easily do that by adding a property "visible" to each of my object and `ng-click="obj.visible = !obj.visible"`. 
But this solution means modifying the object and I don't really want that.
Is there a better solution?

I tried to use track by or a kind of hashmap but without real success.
Should I modify the model and clear it later if I need to save it?

```js
    angular.module('myModule', []);

    angular.module("myModule")
      .controller("DemoCtrl", demoCtrl);

    demoCtrl.$inject = ["$scope"];
    //demoCtrl
    function demoCtrl($scope) {
      vm = this;
      vm.xObjects = [
        { "xname" : "x1",
          "Ys" : [{
            "yname" : "y1",
             "Zs" : [{ "zname" : "z1" },
                     { "zname" : "z2" }]
          },
          {
            "yname" : "y2",
             "Zs" : [{ "zname" : "z3" },
                     { "zname" : "z4" }]
          }]
        },
        { "xname" : "x2",
          "Ys" : [{
            "yname" : "y3",
             "Zs" : [{ "zname" : "z5" },
                     { "zname" : "z6" }]
          },
          {
            "yname" : "y4",
             "Zs" : [{ "zname" : "z7" },
                     { "zname" : "z8" }]
          }]
        }
      ];
      
      vm.addX = function(){
        vm.xObjects.push({ "xname" : "foo", Ys : []});
      }
      vm.addY = function(x){
        x.Ys.push({ "Yname" : "bar", Zs : []});
      }
      vm.addZ = function(y){
        y.Zs.push({ "Zname" : "too"});
      }
    }
```

```html
    <html>
      <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body data-ng-app="myModule">
        <div data-ng-controller="DemoCtrl as demoCtrl" >
          <div data-ng-repeat="xobject in demoCtrl.xObjects">
            <span data-ng-hide="">xobject.xname = {{xobject.xname}}</span>
            <button data-ng-click="">collapse</button>
            <div data-ng-repeat="yobject in xobject.Ys">
              <span data-ng-hide="">- - -yobject.xname = {{yobject.yname}}</span>
              <button data-ng-click="">collapse</button>
              
              <div data-ng-repeat="zobject in yobject.Zs track by $index">
                <span data-ng-hide="">- - -{{$index}}- - -zobject.xname = {{zobject.zname}}</span>
                <button data-ng-click="">collapse</button>
              </div>
              
              - - - - - -<button data-ng-click="demoCtrl.addZ(yobject)">add Z </button>
            </div>
            - - -<button data-ng-click="demoCtrl.addY(xobject)">add Y </button>
          </div>
        <button data-ng-click="demoCtrl.addX()">add X </button>
        </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by creating property named `hidden` in the controller scope. To hide nested element, you can use arrays.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="x in xs">
        <span ng-hide="hidden == $index">{{ x.name }}</span>
        <button ng-click="hide($index)">Collapse</button>

        <div ng-repeat="y in x.ys">
            <span ng-hide="hidden == [x.$index, $index]">{{ y.name }}</span>
            <button ng-click="hide([x.$index, $index])">Collapse</button>

            <div ng-repeat="z in y.zs">
                <span ng-hide="hidden == [x.$index, y.$index, $index]">{{ z.name }}</span>
                <button ng-click="hide([x.$index, y.$index, $index])">Collapse</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this controller:

```
angular.module("app", [])
    .controller("DemoCtrl", function($scope) {
        $scope.xs = [...];  // Your data here

        $scope.hidden = -1; // Nothing hidden yet
        $scope.hide = function(object) {
            $scope.hidden = object;
        };
    });
```

Comment: this does not really answer to the question because with this we can't hide multiple dive in the same time.

Comment: Another way is to make `hidden` property on each object. You can delete these properties later.